# Redirecting twice result in loop error message

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have several product images that I'm no longer using after I updated and restructered the product catalogue. I would delete them, except for the fact that their attachment pages in WordPress have been indexed by Google, so if I did that I reckon the visitor would se a 404 error.

I would automatically redirect from the attachment page to the parent post by changing my theme's image.php to just this: `<?php wp_redirect(get_permalink($post->post_parent)); ?>`, but that gives me the error message:

> This webpage has a redirect loop
>
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I suppose this is happening beacuse the parent post is aready ridirecting to a new and updated page I made to replace the old one.

So is it not allowed to redirect twice? Why is it saying that there'a a loop? It shold redirect from image attachment page to parent post to new page, can't see any loop there. How could I fix this?

Comment: It probably is much easier to simply rewrite the error handler on the level of the http server to redirect requests resulting in a 404 error to some given url.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, missed the obvious solution, [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-redirection/) that I already had installed does the trick nicely. I just redirect directly from each unused image's attachment page to the relevant new page.